# Multiple IDs in a Form used as array

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I stumbled upon this by accident and it works in Chrome and IE9, if I'm not using any other javascript libraries that might require unique ids, is there any specific reason I shouldn't use this?

```
<form id=form_id>
    <table id=table_id>
            <th><th>Column1</th><th>Column2</th><th>Column3</th></tr>
            <tr><td><input id="c1" type="text" value="11" /></td>
                <td><input id="c2" type="text" value="12" /></td>
                <td><input id="c3" type="text" value="13" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td><input id="c1" type="text" value="21" /></td>
                <td><input id="c2" type="text" value="22" /></td>
                <td><input id="c3" type="text" value="23" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td><input id="c1" type="text" value="31" /></td>
                <td><input id="c2" type="text" value="32" /></td>
                <td><input id="c3" type="text" value="33" /></td>
            </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Access an column1 row3 item with: `form_id.elements.c1[2].value` or `document.getElementByID("form_id").elements.c1[2].value`

It seems to me that in this method, multiple occurrences of an id can be treated as an array.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this. Ids are expected (by most developers and JavaScript libraries) to be unique within the page.

Instead, you can identify common elements by giving them the same CSS class. Also, your inputs should have `name` attributes.

Comment: As I said though, I'm not using any Javascript libraries and I'm the only dev on the page. I don't need names because I'm not submitting the form, only accessing it via javascript.